# What does varchar(n) in snowflake mean?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column in snowflake which contain big URLs I have given it varchar(50), does varchar(50) mean it can only store 50 characters?

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does varchar(50) mean it can only store 50 characters?

Yes.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(col VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO t(col) SELECT REPEAT('a', 51);
-- String 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
-- is too long and would be truncated

    
SELECT CAST(REPEAT('a', 51) AS VARCHAR(50));
-- String 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
-- is too long and would be truncated

-- Alternative Way To Cast
SELECT 'aaahhhhhhh'::VARCHAR(5);
-- String 'aaahhhhhhh' is too long and would be truncated
```